# Trouble passing an object to an action in Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I am trying to pass an object to a Vuex action but it does not seem to work for me.

This action is meant to take an object, iterate through it and output a string to go on the end of an API to filter results.

**My component:**

```
  data() {
    return {
      usersData: [],
      modals: {
        removeUser: false,
        id: "",
        filterSearch: false
      },
      filters: {
        role: "user",
        active: "true",
        search: "",
        pageSize: "",
        page: ""
      }
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getUsers();
  },
  methods: {
    getUsers() {
      console.log("object before passed = " + this.filters);
      var params = this.$store.dispatch('getQueryString', this.filters);
    }
  }
```

**store.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import axios from "axios";

Vue.use(Vuex);
Vue.use(axios);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: { },
  mutations: { },
  actions: {
    getQueryString(payload) {
      console.log("object passed = " + payload);
      let paramString = "";
      let counter = 0;
      for (var key in payload) {
        if (payload[key]) {
          let connector = (counter > 0) ? "&" : "?";
          paramString += connector + key + "=" + payload[key];
          counter++;
        }
      }
      return paramString;
    }
  },
```

When I output it in the console, it says: `object before passed = [object Object]` so I know that it is a problem before the object has been passed to the action. Vue seems to be outputting the object as a string, but behaves like an object within this component.

Does anyone know how I can submit the object to this action?

Comment: The payload is the second argument received by the action, not the first argument.

Comment: I would also add that `actions` are asynchronous, so the string you're returning will be wrapped in  Promise. It isn't immediately clear why you're using the store for this at all. If you aren't interacting with store state then a plain JS file would seem a more appropriate home.

Comment: Thanks, yes you are right. I'm fairly new to Vuex and I was hoping to use it for multiple API's across the application. It was returning a promise and it seems that I was using Vuex for the wrong purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `console.log("object passed = " + payload)` use `console.log("object passed = ", payload)` and you should see your object. Use `payload.filters` to read your object inside payload